# Find all instances of value in worksheet and sum the offset values

Tags: excel, vba

I have `wbk1.worksheet(1)` and `wbk2.worksheet(1)`.

`wbk1.worksheet(1)` has a list of values in column A

`wbk2.worksheet(2)` has the same list of values that may occur multiple times in column A with a number value in the `offset(0,1)` cell.

I need to do an index or match to find all of values in wbk2 and sum all of the `offset(0,1)` values.  Then take that sum and put it in the `offset(0,1)` cell in `wbk1.worksheets(1)`.

```
Example:

Workbook 1, sheet 1
Column A     Column B
value 1
value 2 
value 3

Workbook 2, sheet 1
Column A     Column B
value 1         15
value 2         2 
value 1         3 
value 1         12

End Result:
Workbook 1, sheet 1
Column A     Column B
value 1         30
value 2         2
value 3         0

I've tried doing a for each loop, but I'm still a noob to vb, so clearly not doing something right:

For Each x In rngWbk1
        Set cellrngwbk2 = wbk2.Worksheets(1).Cells.Find(What:=x, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not cellrngwbk2 Is Nothing Then
                For Each y In rngwbk1
                    If y = cellrngwbk2 Then
                        total = total + cellrngwbk2.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Else
                    End If
                Next y
                x.Offset(0, 1).Value = total
                total = 0 'resets total value for next x value

        Else
        End If
next x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more efficient way. You can use `SUMIF` formula to calculate values and then rewrite formula with result values. If `rngWbk1` corresponds to the values in column `A` in `wbk1.worksheets(1)`, you can use following code:

```
 Dim frm As String
 Dim startCell As String

 startCell = Replace(rngWbk1.Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, -1).Address, "$", "")
 frm = "=SUMIF('[" & wbk2.Name & "]" & wbk2.Worksheets(1).Name & "'!A:A," & startCell & ", '[" & wbk2.Name & "]" & wbk2.Worksheets(1).Name & "'!B:B)"

 With rngWbk1.Offset(0, 1)
     .Formula = frm
     .Calculate
     .Value = .Value
 End With
```

If `rngWbk1` doesn't correspond values in column `A`,  you need to adjust `startCell` in example to `startCell = "A2"` and change `With rngWbk1.Offset(0, 1)` to sth like `With wbk1.Worksheets(1).Range("B1:B100")`

Comment: I can't get this to work?  It just fills with zeros:  `frm = "=SUMIF('[" & wbkDashboard.name & "]" & wbkDashboard.Worksheets(2).name & "'!A:A," & "'[" & wbkDashboard.name & "]" & wbkDashboard.Worksheets(2).name & "'!" & startCell & ":A" & strDBBOLastRow & "," & "'[" & wbkDashboard.name & "]" & wbkDashboard.Worksheets(2).name & "'!B:B)"

With wbkDashboard.Worksheets(2).Range("D6:D100")
     .Formula = frm
     .Calculate
     .Value = .Value
End With`

Comment: Which gives me: `"=SUMIF('[ProvDashboard.xlsm]Dashboard'!A:A,'[ProvDashboard.xlsm]Dashboard'!A6:A137,'[ProvDashboard.xlsm]Dashboard'!B:B)"`, which seems to be correct?

Comment: it's uncorrect..because you should have sth like this: `"=SUMIF('[ProvDashboard.xlsm]Dashboard'!A:A,A6,'[ProvDashboard.xlsm]Dashboard'!B:B)"`. What is in your `rngWbk1` variable?

Comment: I think I've figured it out! You canged my `frm` statement by adding `& "'[" & wbkDashboard.name & "]" & wbkDashboard.Worksheets(2).name & "'!" & startCell & ":A" & strDBBOLastRow &`. You shoudn't do this. Try to use _my_ `frm`. It should work as you need

Comment: there are two things with your formula: `"=SUMIF('[ProvDashboard.xlsm]Dashboard'!A:A,'[ProvDashboard.xlsm]Dashboard'!A6:‌​A137,'[ProvDashboard.xlsm]Dashboard'!B:B)"` . 1) you should use _single_ value in second attribute (change `'[ProvDashboard.xlsm]Dashboard'!A6:‌​A137` to `'[ProvDashboard.xlsm]Dashboard'!A6`) 2) all values are in the same workbook or you just forgot to change WB name? Btw, try to use this formula at first in worksheet without VBA and then rewrite it in VBA

Comment: Wow.... have I wasted a lot of time on something dumb. :)  You were right from the beginning.  I fat-fingered a field that I didn't catch.  UGH.  Works like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If VBA is not a requirement, a simple `=SUMIF()` statement has the same effect.

The function would look something like this:

```
=SUMIF([Wbk2.xlsx]Sheet1!A2:A5,Table1[[#This Row],[ID]],[Wbk2.xlsx]Sheet1!B2:B5)
```